# development_dependency with github reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemspecs

I'm building an [engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) that needs to work with [Active Admin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin). The idea is engine users include their own Active Admin reference in the `Gemfile`. So, for development purposes, I need to include active admin as **development dependency** on my gem. I tried to add this on my `gem.gemspec`:

```
s.add_development_dependency "activeadmin", github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

But occurs the following error:

```
There was a Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError while loading admin_invitable.gemspec: Illformed requirement [{:github=>"gregbell/active_admin"}]
```

So, the question is: **how can I do this? I mean, how can I specify the `github` option?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sad, but it's **NOT possible** to refer `github` in your `gemspec` file.

As you are doing it just for development sake, you need to remove this dependency from your `gemspec` and add it into your `Gemfile`.

```
gem 'actveadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```